# Can't select/remove automatic legend in layout view

Tags: arcmap, legend

Every time I start a new map and go into layout view it automatically generates a legend, scale bar, and north arrow.  I can select the scale bar and north arrow and remove them, but for some reason I cannot select the legend.  Normally I just get around it by sending it to the back and covering it up, but eventually it pokes out of the top when I have enough layers selected in the TOC.  I've tried closing and re-opening the tools toolbar and editing toolbar to see if the select tool was just not functioning, but to no avail.  Working in ArcMap 10.5.1.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Automatically generating a legend, scale bar, and north arrow is not a regular ArcMap behaviour. Are you using an extension/addin that does this?

Comment: This could be a map template doing the insertions, but that wouldn't prevent you from removing the legend. Have you tried erasing your normal.mxt on your C drive user profile?